# Adding a file into the Runtime Image in WEC7

Tags: windows-ce

In order to include any file in the WEC7 we have to use the bib files.

In my case I created a subproject in which I wrote an application, now I want this application to be included in the run-time image. So I opened the project.bib file and wrote the following entries.

As it is an executable file, it should be in the MODULES Section

MODULES

```
Subproject2.exe  $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\Subproject2.exe              NK
```

When I loaded the image on the device, I checked the Windows folder for the image, it was not present.

But when i wrote this in the FILES section

FILES

```
Subproject2.exe  $(_FLATRELEASEDIR)\Subproject2.exe               NK
```

It is present in the windows folder, may I know the reason?

Is it that for executables we have to keep it in the FILES section?

Or whether I'm doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The MODULES section is for exe's or dll's that you may want to execute in-place, that is, without first loading them into RAM. Modules listed in this section will not be compressed in the final nk.bin image.

The FILES section on the other hand is for files that *can* be compressed in the image without affecting the ability to run in-place. This includes resources like bitmap images, audio and video files, and, perhaps surprisingly, also .NET exe's and dll's which are not real executables in this context (they are always loaded into memory before execution).

So generally, unmanaged/non-.NET executables should be placed in the MODULES section.

When you make changes to the .bib file be aware that, depending on the BSP, you may need to perform a platform sysgen and copy files to the release directory before generating the image.

In Platform Builder 7.0, this is done by right-clicking the Platform name in Solution Explorer and hitting `Sysgen(SysgenPlatform...)`, followed by a trip to the `Build` menu and the `Copy Files to Release Directory` command.

You'll need to do the same if you change any .reg, .dat or .db files.

Notice that you can load the nk.bin file directly in Platform Builder to inspect its contents, files, registry entries, etc. This can potentially save some time compared to installing the image in the target. Just go through the `File` menu, `Open`, `File...` and navigate to the nk.bin file.